# combine change active li and reload part of page javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have two simple function on click in my page with js, first is to change css active in current li and the other is to reload content only .

change active li

```
$(".list li").on("click", function(){
    $(".list li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

reload content only

```
$('.content').load('Passtel/dashboard');
$('ul.list li a').click(function(){
   var page = $(this).attr('href');
   $('.content').load('Passtel/'+page);
   return false;
});
```

the problem is, it just function reload content only works if there two are running, but I've tested each of function works as it is.

How can I make both of function works together?

this is my content structure

```
        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="dashboard">
                        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
                        <span>DASHBOARD</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="check">
                        <i class="material-icons">text_fields</i>
                        <span>CHECK SITE</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="datek">
                        <i class="material-icons">layers</i>
                        <span>DATA TEKNIS</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: What is the HTML structure?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM I update my question with my html structure,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.content').load('Passtel/dashboard');
    $('ul.list li a').click(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".list li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');  //added parent() here
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.content').load('Passtel/' + page);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```js
//$('.content').load('Passtel/dashboard');
$('ul.list li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 $(".list li").removeClass('active');
 $(this).parent().addClass('active');
 var page = $(this).attr('href');
 //$('.content').load('Passtel/' + page);
 return false;
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="dashboard">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    <span>DASHBOARD</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="check">
    <i class="material-icons">text_fields</i>
    <span>CHECK SITE</span>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="datek">
    <i class="material-icons">layers</i>
    <span>DATA TEKNIS</span>
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's doesn't work too, the page reload just like before, but active li is stuck in first li.

Comment: Can try my code above. Use `e.preventDefault()`. Do note that I commented out the code which does load.

Comment: e.preventDefault() the missing line. I add e in $('ul.list li a').click(function () become $('ul.list li a').click(function (e) and thats works, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with only one function. Hope it helps!

[jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/yutoti/embed?html,js,output)

```
const ul = $(".list");
const list = ul.find('li');

ul.on("click", 'li a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  list.removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');

  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  // replace this with your $('.content').load('Passtel/'+page);
  $('.content').load('https://jgatjens.com/?' + page);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, thats work and it's help a lot, :D